# In wpf, how to set run background height to line height?

Tags: c#, wpf, styles, richtextbox, flowdocument

Is there a way to set the background `Height` of a `Run` element the same as the `LineHeight` in WPF? Here is the demo of my question and the yellow background is my expected height. 
[Demo of my question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hkO3l.png)

```
    <RichTextBox IsReadOnly="True" Focusable="False" BorderThickness="0">
    <FlowDocument>
        <Paragraph LineHeight="30" LineStackingStrategy="BlockLineHeight">
            <Run>How to set the run element background height as LineHeight?</Run>
            <Run Background="Gray">How to set the run element background height as LineHeight?</Run>
            <Run>How to set the run element background height as LineHeight?</Run>
        </Paragraph>
    </FlowDocument>
</RichTextBox>
```

Comment: Have you tried https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6xe5hazb(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thank you but I don't think this would work in this case.

Comment: Did you try creating a Rect starting at the Run's `ElementStart.GetCharacterRect(LogicalFlowDirection.Forward).TopLeft` and going to the Run's `ElementEnd.GetNextInsertionPosition(LogicalFlowDirection.Backward).GetCharacterRect(LogicalFlowDirection.Forward).BottomRight`, then changing that Rect's background to your color? Not sure if it would do what you're asking because I've never done it, but it might be worth it to try.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I have the same question.